# Album details from iTunes using API

Tags: php, api, itunes

I have an application for streaming audio( On-line FM Channel ).I have to get the details about an album that currently playing on the Radio.I have only Album Title and Artist Name.
the Track Id of the songs is getting null from the API (I am using TD Player API).

The main issue is i don't get all info of the songs like cover url , order by url (itunes store) etc. But when i get this track id i can get all details of the songs from itunes store using their API.

So My qstion is any way to get the track id or full album info from itunes using Album Title and Artist Name.??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Search API has a few parameters that will help qualify the content you want returned.

Firstly, you cannot search on the Album title and Artist at the same time.  You can put both in the "term" field and hope for the best, but you are better off searching at the Album level if you know it.

https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=Live+at+Wembley+Stadium&attribute=albumTerm&entity=song

attribute=albumTerm indicates to the API that you want your "term" strictly related to album titles and not any of the other meta info.

entity=song tells the API that you want all the songs returned and not just the Album info (default).

Furthermore, if you have only the Artist name, your search may look like this:

https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=Queen&attribute=artistTerm&entity=song&limit=300

Unfortunately this returns 300 songs by Queen.  You will need to further refine your search if the link you are expecting is not returned in this request.

Comment: thanks for your rply..The main issue is that i have only album title and artistname. When i search with artist name like "PSY" it will return result that artist name contain PSY not only PSY's albums.So It will not suitable for my requirement.From the API iam getting only these two info..

Comment: Does this help?  Asking for only "album" returned will keep songs and music videos from getting returned:  https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=PSY&attribute=artistTerm&entity=album

Comment: Ultimately you want to get the artistid for PSY and use the lookup to ensure you get "only" the PSY albums you are expecting: https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=554290495&entity=album

Comment: This also works same the result contain "artistName":"PSY" and "artistName":"Goa Psy Trance Masters" .We can't make sure both artist are same like Justin Bieber and Justin ,both result will comes :(

Comment: Yes that is correct but the issue is here used one id that is the track id of the album,My API will not return this track id that is the issue.. :( :(